# Settings Fields not showing up in Submenu Page

Tags: plugins, settings-api

I'm working on my first plugin. I am having difficulty getting the settings_fields function to display the results of the settings fields' callback functions. I've been studying the settings api, but I cannot figure out where I've gone wrong. I've attached a screenshot of what is rendering, as well as the code in question. Thanks for any help provided.

Result:
[image: the results of do_settings_sections shows up, but not settings_fields]

```
if(!class_exists('ce_add_scripts')){

    class ce_add_scripts{

        function __construct(){
            add_action('admin_init', array(&$this,'ceas_admin_init'));
            add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this,'ceas_admin_menu'));
            add_action('wp_head', array(&$this,'ceas_wp_head'));
            add_action('wp_footer', array(&$this,'ceas_wp_footer'));
        }

        function ceas_admin_menu(){
            add_submenu_page(
                'tools.php', 
                'CE Add Scripts', 
                'CE Add Scripts', 
                'update_plugins', 
                'ceas_menu_page', 
                array(&$this,'ceas_page_callback') );
        }

        function ceas_admin_init(){
            $args= array(
                'type'=>'string',
                'default'=>NULL,);

            register_setting(
                'ceas_options', 
                'ceas_main_settings', 
                $args);

            add_settings_section(
                'ceas_options_section',
                'Insert Scripts to Head or Footer',
                array(&$this,'ceas_section_display'),
                'ceas_menu_page');

            add_settings_field(
                'ceas_options_field_0',
                'Head Script Entry',
                'ceas_head_script',
                'CE Add Scripts',
                'ceas_options_section');

            add_settings_field(
                'ceas_options_field_1',
                'Footer Script Entry',
                'ceas_footer_script',
                'CE Add Scripts',
                'ceas_options_section');
        }

        function ceas_section_display(){
            echo 'Add scripts to the Head or Footer';
        }

        function ceas_head_script(){
            $options = get_option('ceas_main_settings');

            echo "<textarea cols='40' rows='5' name='ceas_main_settings[ceas_options_field_0]'>";
            echo $options['ceas_options_field_0'];
            echo "</textarea>";
        }

        function ceas_footer_script(){
            $options = get_option('ceas_main_settings');

            echo "<textarea cols='40' rows='5' name='ceas_main_settings[ceas_options_field_1]'>";
            echo $options['ceas_options_field_1'];
            echo "</textarea>";
        }

        function ceas_page_callback(){

            echo "<div class='wrap'>

            <form action='options.php' method='post'>

            <h1>CE Add Scripts Settings</h1>";

            settings_fields("ceas_options");
            do_settings_sections('ceas_menu_page');
            submit_button();


            echo "</form> 
            </div>";
        }

    }

    $ce_actualize= new ce_add_scripts();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The the code below:

```
if(!class_exists('ce_add_scripts')){

    class ce_add_scripts{

        function __construct(){
            add_action('admin_init', array(&$this,'ceas_admin_init'));
            add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this,'ceas_admin_menu'));
            add_action('wp_head', array(&$this,'ceas_wp_head'));
            add_action('wp_footer', array(&$this,'ceas_wp_footer'));
        }

        function ceas_admin_menu(){
            add_submenu_page(
                'tools.php', 
                'CE Add Scripts', 
                'CE Add Scripts', 
                'update_plugins', 
                'ceas_menu_page', 
                array(&$this,'ceas_page_callback') );
        }

        function ceas_admin_init(){
            $args= array(
                'type'=>'string',
                'default'=>NULL,);

            register_setting(
                'ceas_options', 
                'ceas_main_settings', 
                $args);

            add_settings_section(
                'ceas_options_section',
                'Insert Scripts to Head or Footer',
                array(&$this,'ceas_section_display'),
                'ceas_menu_page');

            add_settings_field(
                'ceas_options_field_0',
                'Head Script Entry',
                'ceas_head_script',
                'CE Add Scripts',
                'ceas_options_section');

            add_settings_field(
                'ceas_options_field_1',
                'Footer Script Entry',
                'ceas_footer_script',
                'CE Add Scripts',
                'ceas_options_section');
        }

        function ceas_section_display(){
            echo 'Add scripts to the Head or Footer';
        }

        function ceas_head_script(){
            $options = get_option('ceas_main_settings');
            if(!isset($options['ceas_options_field_0'])){
                $options['ceas_options_field_0'] = '';
            }
            echo "<textarea cols='40' rows='5' name='ceas_main_settings[ceas_options_field_0]'>";
            echo $options['ceas_options_field_0'];
            echo "</textarea>";
        }

        function ceas_footer_script(){
            $options = get_option('ceas_main_settings');
            if(!isset($options['ceas_options_field_1'])){
                $options['ceas_options_field_1'] = '';
            }
            echo "<textarea cols='40' rows='5' name='ceas_main_settings[ceas_options_field_1]'>";
            echo $options['ceas_options_field_1'];
            echo "</textarea>";
        }

        function ceas_page_callback(){

            echo "<div class='wrap'>

            <form action='options.php' method='post'>

            <h1>CE Add Scripts Settings</h1>";

            settings_fields("ceas_options");
            do_settings_sections('ceas_menu_page');
            $this->ceas_head_script();
            $this->ceas_footer_script();
            submit_button();


            echo "</form> 
            </div>";
        }

    }

    $ce_actualize= new ce_add_scripts();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some comments as to what you changed and why it's different?